# How to group json elements for exchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket

I have some problem for group json element.  I want calculate live price depth but i need use parametric decimal.

I have this json from websocket with binance api.

```
{
  "symbol": "btcusdt",
  "depth": [
    {
      "price": 38980,
      "qty": 1.34
    },
    {
      "price": 39100,
      "qty": 1.34
    },
    {
      "price": 39200,
      "qty": 2.44
    },
    {
      "price": 39500,
      "qty": 7.31
    },
    {
      "price": 40230,
      "qty": 11.34
    }
  ]
}
```

i need group prices with quantity. Sample :

```
{
  "symbol": "btcusdt",
  "depth": [
    {
      "price": 38000,
      "qty": 1.34
    },
    {
      "price": 39000,
      "qty": 11.09
    },
    {
      "price": 40000,
      "qty": 11.34
    }
  ]
}
```

I using websocket for this. Json element always refresh.

Comment: What do you mean by "group?"

Comment: @Spectric It looks like he's combining all the elements in the same thousands range, summing the quantities.

Answer (score 3):

Reduce the `depth` array into an object whose keys are the price rounded down to the a multiple of 1000.

```js
const data = {
  "symbol": "btcusdt",
  "depth": [{
      "price": 38000,
      "qty": 1.34
    },
    {
      "price": 39000,
      "qty": 11.09
    },
    {
      "price": 40000,
      "qty": 11.34
    }
  ]
};

data.depth = Object.values(data.depth.reduce((acc, {
  price,
  qty
}) => {
  let thousands = price - price % 1000;
  if (acc[thousands]) {
    acc[thousands].qty += qty;
  } else {
    acc[thousands] = {
      price: thousands,
      qty: qty
    };
  }
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sorter object. set the floored price as the key, then iterate.

after parsing your json

```js
const myJson = {
  "symbol": "btcusdt",
  "depth": [{
      "price": 38980,
      "qty": 1.34
    },
    {
      "price": 39100,
      "qty": 1.34
    },
    {
      "price": 39200,
      "qty": 2.44
    },
    {
      "price": 39500,
      "qty": 7.31
    },
    {
      "price": 40230,
      "qty": 11.34
    }
  ]
}

let foo = {}, sorted = []
myJson.depth.forEach(entry => {
  let price = Math.floor(entry.price / 1000) * 1000

  if (foo[price]) {
    foo[price].qty += entry.qty
  } else {
    entry.price = price
    foo[price] = entry
  }
})

sorted = {
  symbol: myJson.symbol,
  depth: Object.values(foo)
}

console.log(sorted)
```

most efficient way I've found doing this at least..